# return with while and if else loop

Tags: java

I've the below method which expects a return type as SomeObject. mapData() function returns SomeObject. I want to come out from the loop as soon as one condition gets satisfied. I'm getting compilation error due to no return type found. Can you please point out the issue with my condition ?

```
 public static SomeObject mapper(List<String> mylist) {
    Iterator iter = mylist.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Object[] result = (Object[]) iter.next();
            if (condition){
                //dosomething
                return mapData(abc);
            }else if (condition) {
                //dosomething
                return mapData(def);
            }else {
                //dosomething
                return mapData(ghi);
            }
    }
  // Get compilation error due to no return type at this position
}
```

Comment: You can add a `return null;` after the `while` loop. Geez... Now looking how people crawl for rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine what happens when your `while` loop never executes? This will happen if your list is empty. In that case, your method would not return anything, thus the error.

Just add a return statement:

```
return null;
```

after your `while` loop. Or return some default instance of `SomeObject`, if you haven't done the `null` check for the value returned by this method.

Comment: @PravatPanda in fact, returning a `null` is a design matter as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/271526/1065197). IMO I would prefer to evaluate if the method *should* return `null` or not instead of just setting a `return null` at the bottom. And if you prefer to not return anything at all after the `while` loop, you can throw an exception (or a `RuntimeException` if want to be silent) and handle the exception in the caller as explained in arshajii answer which can lead to another design.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. True. Should have added this earlier. Thnx :)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler requires that all possible code paths either

- `return` a value
- `throw` an exception

You should do whichever makes more sense in the context of your program, in your case that means adding one of these statements to the end of your method.

Answer (score 0):

Add `return null;` (or) relevant `return` statement at the end.

If none of the conditions satisfied in your while loop, then this will be returned.